# Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module) (Read 10 times)

Tags: macos, arduino, iot, esp8266

OS: Mac OS X Version 10.10.5
Python --version: Python 3.7.2

Error message:
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _getentropy
Referenced from: /Users/xxxx/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/python3/3.7.2-post1/python3
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _getentropy
Referenced from: /Users/xxxx/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/python3/3.7.2-post1/python3
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

signal: trace/BPT trap
/Users/xxxx/Downloads/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder returned 255
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).

Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: This is still happening, in August, with Arduino 1.8.13. When will this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

MacoS 10.11.6 (15G22010), Arduino IDE 1.8.13, Board: Wemos D1 R1 (esp8266)

same problem, since yesterday, when compiling on a wemos d1 r1 card

While waiting for the fix, I went down to version 2.5.0 and it works. from version 2.6.0 it does not work. same message.